# Looping (?) and setting values Access VBA

Tags: vba, loops

I am writing a medication administration app. The main table name is ResidentMedications. The second table name is Resident24HourTable. My main form is ResidentMedicationsExtended, with a subform Resident24HourPeriod. Resident24HourPeriod contains 24 check boxes, one for each hour in the day. (12A, 1A, 2A, 3A etc).

Within the ResidentMedicationsExtended form is a combo box [Frequency]. For simplicity sake, let's say "Q4H" is selected, for "4 times per day". Another field [First Dose] allows the user to enter the time the resident will receive their first daily dose. We'll say 6:00 AM.

I have a command button that I want to check the appropriate times in the subform based on the Frequency and First Dose fields. So far, I have written the following:

```
Private Sub Command90_Click()
If Me.FirstDose = "12:00:00 AM" Then
Forms!ResidentMedicationsExtended.Form.Resident24HourTable![12A] = True
ElseIf Me.FirstDose = "1:00:00 AM" Then
Forms!ResidentMedicationsExtended.Form.Resident24HourTable![1A] = True
ElseIf Me.FirstDose = "2:00:00 AM" Then
Forms!ResidentMedicationsExtended.Form.Resident24HourTable![2A] = True
ElseIf Me.FirstDose = "3:00:00 AM" Then
Forms!ResidentMedicationsExtended.Form.Resident24HourTable![3A] = True
```

and so on and so forth - many many lines. I know I can write separate lines for each time, write more to make checkboxes False, etc. Obviously, doing it this way will result in a zillion or so lines of code, and I have yet to calculate the rest of the days medication times.

Is there a Loop or something I can use instead? I've read loads of posts and haven't been able to come up with a solution.

I thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

4 times in a day means [once every 6 hours].  In your dropdown boxes, you should display the text description, but for the key, use values that make it easier to do the math. Use the period between occurrances, in terms of hours. Then it will be easier to use a loop to run through the occurrances (until you have covered a 24-hour period).
Another alternative would be to use date calculation functions like CDate(), DateAdd() and DatePart() to calculate time values.

So, for your example: 4 times a day. Your list value would be 6 (6 hour intervals)

```
Private Sub Command30_Click()

Dim totalHours as integer
Dim interval as integer
interval = *** the value from your interval dropdown, eg 6 (hours) ***

Dim nextDose as integer
nextDose = Me.FirstDose ' text was 12 am, but stored in 24 hour format as 0

While totalHours < 24
   Forms!ResidentMedicationsExtended.Form.Resident24HourTable![nextDose] = True
   nextDose = nextDose + interval
   totalHours = totalHours + interval
Wend 'or End While
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Hour()` and `TimeValue()` to convert "1:00:00 AM" to 1, etc., then use this number to identify the Control:

```
Dim hrFirst As Integer

hrFirst = Hour(TimeValue(Me.FirstDose)) 'returns 0 for 12am, 1 for 1am
hrFirst = IIF(hrFirst = 0, 12, hrFirst)

Forms!ResidentMedicationsExtended.Form.Resident24HourTable.Controls(hrFirst & "A") = True
```